# How to migrate JAXB context from MULE 3 to MULE 4?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-esb, mule4

I have a JAXB context configured in a MULE 3 project:

```
<mulexml:jaxb-context name="JAXB_Context" packageNames="com.company.util" doc:name="JAXB Context" />
<spring:beans>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.company.package" />
</spring:beans>
```

After running the migration tool, the config is shortened to just this:

```
<mulexml:jaxb-context name="JAXB_Context" packageNames="com.company.util" doc:name="JAXB Context" />
```

In Global Elements section this element is of type `Unknown`.

I have absolutely no errors, warnings or info in the migration report about this element.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

`<mulexml:jaxb-context>` is no longer supported in Mule 4. The migration tool can not migrate it because it is just not supported. According to the docs ([Migrating the XML Module](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/migration-connectors-xml)):

> No longer tied to Java: It no longer uses SAX, StaX, or DOM types.
> Mule 4 is now strongly typed and we have mime type information about
> which data is in XML format. The runtime does the rest. All XML
> documents are represented as either Strings or streams. This means the
> following no longer exist (and are no longer needed):
>
> - dom-to-xml-transformer
> - dom-to-output-handler-transformer
> - xml-to-dom-transformer
> - xml-prettyprinter-transformer
> - jaxb-object-to-xml-transformer
> - jaxb-xml-to-object-transformer
> - jaxb-context
> - object-to-xml-transformer
> - xml-to-object-transformer

You will have to decide if there is really a reason to use JAXB in your Mule 4 applications. I guess if you need it you will have to limit its usage to inside Java classes, without communicating JAXB over class boundaries.